# Modifying a semaphore stored in an instance variable from within an Objective-C block

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, metal

Apple offers a [CPU and GPU Synchronization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/synchronization/cpu_and_gpu_synchronization?language=objc) sample project that shows how to synchronize access to shared resources between CPU and GPU. To do so, it uses a semaphore which is stored in an instance variable:

```
@implementation AAPLRenderer
{
  dispatch_semaphore_t _inFlightSemaphore;
  // other ivars
}
```

This semaphore is then defined in another method:

```
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithMetalKitView:(nonnull MTKView *)mtkView
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        _device = mtkView.device;

        _inFlightSemaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(MaxBuffersInFlight);

        // further initializations
    }

    return self;
}
```

`MaxBuffersInFlight` is defined as follows:

```
// The max number of command buffers in flight
static const NSUInteger MaxBuffersInFlight = 3;
```

Finally, the semaphore is utilized as follows:

```
/// Called whenever the view needs to render
- (void)drawInMTKView:(nonnull MTKView *)view
{
    // Wait to ensure only MaxBuffersInFlight number of frames are getting processed
    //   by any stage in the Metal pipeline (App, Metal, Drivers, GPU, etc)
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(_inFlightSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    // Iterate through our Metal buffers, and cycle back to the first when we've written to MaxBuffersInFlight
    _currentBuffer = (_currentBuffer + 1) % MaxBuffersInFlight;

    // Update data in our buffers
    [self updateState];

    // Create a new command buffer for each render pass to the current drawable
    id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [_commandQueue commandBuffer];
    commandBuffer.label = @"MyCommand";

    // Add completion hander which signals _inFlightSemaphore when Metal and the GPU has fully
    //   finished processing the commands we're encoding this frame.  This indicates when the
    //   dynamic buffers filled with our vertices, that we're writing to this frame, will no longer
    //   be needed by Metal and the GPU, meaning we can overwrite the buffer contents without
    //   corrupting the rendering.
    __block dispatch_semaphore_t block_sema = _inFlightSemaphore;
    [commandBuffer addCompletedHandler:^(id<MTLCommandBuffer> buffer)
    {
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(block_sema);
    }];

    // rest of the method
}
```

What I fail to understand here is the necessity of the line

```
__block dispatch_semaphore_t block_sema = _inFlightSemaphore;
```

Why do I have to copy the instance variable into a local variable and mark this local variable with `__block`. If I just drop that local variable and instead write

```
[commandBuffer addCompletedHandler:^(id<MTLCommandBuffer> buffer)
{
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(_inFlightSemaphore);
}];
```

It *seems* to work as well. I also tried to mark the instance variable with `__block` as follows:

```
__block dispatch_semaphore_t _bufferAccessSemaphore;
```

This compiles with Clang and *seems* to work as well. But because this is about preventing race conditions I want to be *sure* that it works.

So the question is why does Apple create that local semaphore copy marked with `__block`? Is it really necessary or does the approach with directly accessing the instance variable work just as well?

As a side note, the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10565431/5548098) SO question remarks that marking instance variables with `__block` can't be done. The answer is according to gcc but why would Clang allow this if it shouldn't be done?

Comment: It should work without __block I would think.  The main thing is to avoid the reference to self->_inFlightSemaphore inside the block, which would strongly retain self instead of just the semaphore, which the local variable solves.  __block on instance variables should be meaningless since they are always accessed indirectly through self->xxx; perhaps clang just hasn't bothered to make the declaration illegal there even though it has no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important semantic distinction here is that when you use the ivar directly in the block, the block takes a strong reference to `self`. By creating a local variable that refers to the semaphore instead, only the semaphore is captured (by reference) by the block, instead of `self`, reducing the likelihood of a retain cycle.

As for the `__block` qualifier, you'd normally use that to indicate that a local variable should be mutable within the referencing block. However, since the semaphore *variable* is not mutated by the call to `signal`, the qualifier isn't strictly necessary here. It still serves a useful purpose from a style perspective, though, in the sense that it emphasizes the lifetime and purpose of the variable.

On the topic of why an ivar can be qualified with `__block`,

> why would Clang allow this if it shouldn't be done?

Perhaps exactly because capturing an ivar in a block implies strongly capturing `self`. With or without a `__block` qualifier, if you use an ivar in a block, you're potentially running the risk of a retain cycle, so having the qualifier there doesn't create additional risk. Better to use a local variable (which, by the way, could be a `__weak` reference to `self` just as easily as a `__block`-qualified reference to an ivar) to be explicit and safe.

Comment: That makes sense to me. Thanks a lot for that insightful answer. So, essentially the execution of the block itself would cause another strong reference to the instance of the `AAPLRenderer` class. In my own renderer I explicitly stop the rendering loop (from which the execution of the block gets triggered) before I stop using the renderer. In that case the strong reference created by the block would automatically go away and there shouldn't be much of a danger regarding a retain cycle. Would you in general agree with this?

Comment: @ackh - I still would be wary about referencing the ivar (with the concomitant `self` reference) in `addCompletedHandler`. It’s not a question as to whether the “block gets triggered”, but rather, whether the block was released after it was triggered. Well written completion handler code will generally release the block when it’s done with it, but are you 100% sure that’s the case here? As a rule, I’d suggest writing code that makes strong reference cycles impossible (i.e. just use local var here), rather than hoping and/or relying on other code to not allow the cycle.

Comment: Good answer, but you go on to suggest it “... could be a `__weak` reference to `self` just as easily as a `__block`-qualified reference to an ivar) to be explicit and safe.” Often that’s the case, but not here. A weak self reference could end up being `nil` and it would be incorrect to call `dispatch_semaphore_wait`/`signal` with a `nil` value for the semaphore. In this case, local var (with or without `__block` qualifier) is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I think warrenm correctly [answered your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55245614/1271826) as to why one would use a local variable rather than the ivar (and its implicit reference to `self`). +1

But you asked about why a local variable would marked as `__block` in this case. The author could have done that to make his/her intent explicit (e.g., to indicate the variable will outlive the scope of the method). Or they could have potentially done it for the sake of efficiency (e.g., why make a new copy of the pointer?).

For example, consider:

```
- (void)foo {
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(4);
    NSLog(@"foo: %p %@", &semaphore, semaphore);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
            NSLog(@"bar: %p %@", &semaphore, semaphore);
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
        });
    }
}
```

While these are all using the same semaphore, in the absence of `__block`, each dispatched block will get its own pointer to that semaphore.

However, if you add `__block` to the declaration of that local `semaphore` variable, and each dispatched block will use the same pointer which will be sitting on the heap (i.e. the address of `&semaphore` will be the same for each block).

It’s not meaningful here, IMHO, where there’s only one block being dispatched, but hopefully this illustrates the impact of `__block` qualifier on local var. (Obviously, the traditional use of `__block` qualifier is if you’re changing the value of the object in question, but that’s not relevant here.)

> ... marking instance variables with `__block` can't be done [in gcc] ... but why would Clang allow this if it shouldn't be done?

Regarding why no error on `__block` for ivars, as that referenced answer said, it’s basically redundant. I’m not sure that just because something is redundant that it should be disallowed.